# How to remove addEventListener when jumping between frames in Animate CC HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs, animate-cc

I seem to have trouble removing addEventListeners when I jump between frames. When I jump back and forth, the addEventListeners still seem to stack up:

[image]

Frame 1 code:

```
this.stop();

this.arrowForward_btn.addEventListener("click", arrow_btnClickForward.bind(this));

function arrow_btnClickForward() {
    this.arrowForward_btn.removeEventListener("click", arrow_btnClickForward.bind(this));
    console.log("went forward");
    alert("alert: went forward!");
    this.gotoAndStop(1);
}
```

Frame 2 code:

```
this.arrowBack_btn.addEventListener("click", arrow_btnClickBack.bind(this));

function arrow_btnClickBack() {
    this.arrowBack_btn.removeEventListener("click", arrow_btnClickBack.bind(this));
    console.log("went back!");
    alert("alert: went back!");
    this.gotoAndStop(0);
}
```

How do I remove the addEventListeners so that they don't stack up?

---

**Update:** Was told about evt.remove(); so I used that in my codes and it works:

Frame 1 code:

```
this.stop();

this.arrowForward_btn.addEventListener("click", arrow_btnClickForward.bind(this));

function arrow_btnClickForward() {
    console.log("went forward");
    alert("alert: went forward!");
    this.gotoAndStop(1);
    evt.remove();
}
```

Frame 2 code:

```
this.arrowBack_btn.addEventListener("click", arrow_btnClickBack.bind(this));

function arrow_btnClickBack(evt) {
    console.log("went back!");
    alert("alert: went back!");
    this.gotoAndStop(0);
    evt.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your update is *better*, but it might help to explain a few things:

- When you use `bind()`, it generates a new unique closure. Every time.
- You need to use this *exact* closure when you remove the event. Generating another one, even with the same parameters, will not work.

Note that `evt.remove()` should work for you, but in your first example (frame 1 code), the event handler doesn't have an `evt` param.

A few things in CreateJS might help:

1. The `on()` method is a shortcut for addEventListener, which helps you do things like pass scope

```
this.arrowForward_btn.on("click", arrow_btnClickForward, this);
```

2. It also has a `once` parameter, so if you know your event will fire one time, it can get auto-removed.

```
this.arrowForward_btn.on("click", arrow_btnClickForward, this, true);
```

3. If you still want to manually manage, `on()` returns the generated closure. You can use `off()` to remove easily.

```
var handler = this.arrowForward_btn.on("click", arrow_btnClickForward, this);
// later
this.arrowForward.off("click", handler);
```

Hopefully that gives you a better understanding of event handlers in CreateJS, and some combination of that will work.

--

It might also be helpful to know that you can write **all** your code in the first frame, since CreateJS bootstraps instances in every frame when the movieclip is initialized. So `arrowBack_btn` will exist in frame 1 as well. You could just add the code once, and ensure it only run

```
if (this.inited == false) {
  this.inited = true;

  this.arrowForward_btn.on("click", arrow_btnClickForward, this);
    this.arrowBack_btn.on("click", arrow_btnClickBack, this);

    function arrow_btnClickForward() {
        console.log("went forward");
        alert("alert: went forward!");
        this.gotoAndStop(1);
    }

    function arrow_btnClickBack(evt) {
        console.log("went back!");
        alert("alert: went back!");
        this.gotoAndStop(0);
    }

}
```

I didn't test this, but it should work :D

Comment: Thank you for the insight! This will help me when I refer back to this again in the future.